# Representing a theorem with multiple hypotheses in Lean (propositional logic)

Tags: lean

Real beginners question here.  How do I represent a problem with multiple hypotheses in Lean?  For example:

Given

- A
- A→B
- A→C
- B→D
- C→D

Prove the proposition D.

(Problem taken from The [Incredible Proof Machine](http://incredible.pm/), Session 2 problem 3.  I was actually reading [Logic and Proof, Chapter 4, Propositional Logic in Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/propositional_logic_in_lean.html) but there are less exercises available there)

Obviously this is completely trivial to prove by applying modus ponens twice, my question is how do I represent the problem in the first place?!  Here's my proof:

```
variables A B C D : Prop

example : (( A    )
    /\     ( A->B )
    /\     ( A->C )
    /\     ( B->D )
    /\     ( C->D ))
-> D :=
assume h,
have given1: A, from and.left h,
have given2: A -> B, from and.left (and.right h),
have given3: A -> C, from and.left (and.right (and.right h)),
have given4: B -> D, from and.left (and.right (and.right (and.right h))),
have given5: C -> D, from and.right (and.right (and.right (and.right h))),
show D, from given4 (given2 given1)
```

[Try it!](https://leanprover.github.io/live/3.3.0/#code=variables%20A%20B%20C%20D%20:%20Prop%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aexample%20:%20((%20A%20%20%20%20)%0A%20%20%20%20/%5C%20%20%20(%20A-%3EB%20)%0A%20%20%20%20/%5C%20%20%20(%20A-%3EC%20)%0A%20%20%20%20/%5C%20%20%20(%20B-%3ED%20)%0A%20%20%20%20/%5C%20%20%20(%20C-%3ED%20))%0A-%3E%20D%20:=%0Aassume%20h,%0Ahave%20given1:%20A,%20from%20and.left%20h,%0Ahave%20given2:%20A%20-%3E%20B,%20from%20and.left%20(and.right%20h),%0Ahave%20given3:%20A%20-%3E%20C,%20from%20and.left%20(and.right%20(and.right%20h)),%0Ahave%20given4:%20B%20-%3E%20D,%20from%20and.left%20(and.right%20(and.right%20(and.right%20h))),%0Ahave%20given5:%20C%20-%3E%20D,%20from%20and.right%20(and.right%20(and.right%20(and.right%20h))),%0Ashow%20D,%20from%20given4%20(given2%20given1))

I think I've made far too much a meal of packaging up the problem then unpacking it, could someone show me a better way of representing this problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a lot clearer by not using And in the hypotheses instead using ->. here are 2 equivalent proofs, I prefer the first

```
def s2p3 {A B C D : Prop} (ha : A)
      (hab : A -> B) (hac : A -> C)
      (hbd : B -> D) (hcd : C -> D) : D
  := show D, from (hbd (hab ha))
```

The second is the same as the first except using example,
I believe you have to specify the names of the parameters using assume
rather than inside the declaration

```
example : A -> (A -> B) -> (A -> C) -> (B -> D) -> (C -> D) -> D :=
assume ha : A,
assume hab : A -> B,
assume hac, -- You can actually just leave the types off the above 2
assume hbd, 
assume hcd,
show D, from (hbd (hab ha))
```

if you want to use the def syntax but the problem is e.g. specified using example syntax

```
example : A -> (A -> B) -> (A -> C)
            -> (B -> D) -> (C -> D) -> D := s2p3
```

Also, when using and in your proof, in the unpacking stage
You unpack given3, and given 5 but never use them in your "show" proof.
So you don't need to unpack them e.g.

```
example : (( A    )
    /\     ( A->B )
    /\     ( A->C )
    /\     ( B->D )
    /\     ( C->D ))
-> D :=
assume h,
have given1: A, from and.left h,
have given2: A -> B, from and.left (and.right h),
have given4: B -> D, from and.left (and.right (and.right (and.right h))),
show D, from given4 (given2 given1)
```

Comment: Note that your first proof still works if you replace `def s2p3` with `example`.

Comment: so it does, for some reason i never realized example could take (h : A) : A named parameter syntax, thanks!